# How to get subdirectory paths to work in Python?

Tags: python, jupyter, stock

When I have `20211221_A.csv` in the same level as my `main.ipynb` I am able to print out the contents:

```
stocks2 = pd.read_csv('20211221_A.csv')
print(stocks2)
```

returns:

```
     Unnamed: 0        date minute     label     high      low     open  \
0             0  2021-12-21  09:30  09:30 AM  151.200  150.800  151.130   
1             1  2021-12-21  09:31  09:31 AM  151.430  151.430  151.430   
2             2  2021-12-21  09:32  09:32 AM  151.250  151.150  151.250   
3             3  2021-12-21  09:33  09:33 AM  151.530  151.345  151.345   
4             4  2021-12-21  09:34  09:34 AM  151.375  151.290  151.375   
..          ...         ...    ...       ...      ...      ...      ...
```

However, when I try to get the same file from my subdirectory:

```
stocks = pd.read_csv('script\output\2021\2021-CW51\20211221\DONE\20211221_A.csv')
print(stocks)
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_11384/716366264.py in <module>
----> 1 stocks = pd.read_csv('script\output\2021\2021-CW51\20211221\DONE\20211221_A.csv')
      2 print(stocks)
      3 
      4 # stocks2 = pd.read_csv('20211221_A.csv')
      5 # print(stocks2)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    309                     stacklevel=stacklevel,
    310                 )
--> 311             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    312 
    313         return wrapper

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py in read_csv(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, encoding_errors, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, on_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision, storage_options)
    584     kwds.update(kwds_defaults)
    585 
--> 586     return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    587 
    588 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    480 
    481     # Create the parser.
--> 482     parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
    483 
    484     if chunksize or iterator:

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    809             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    810 
--> 811         self._engine = self._make_engine(self.engine)
    812 
    813     def close(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1038             )
   1039         # error: Too many arguments for "ParserBase"
-> 1040         return mapping[engine](self.f, **self.options)  # type: ignore[call-arg]
   1041 
   1042     def _failover_to_python(self):

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\c_parser_wrapper.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
     49 
     50         # open handles
---> 51         self._open_handles(src, kwds)
     52         assert self.handles is not None
     53 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\base_parser.py in _open_handles(self, src, kwds)
    220         Let the readers open IOHandles after they are done with their potential raises.
    221         """
--> 222         self.handles = get_handle(
    223             src,
    224             "r",

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py in get_handle(path_or_buf, mode, encoding, compression, memory_map, is_text, errors, storage_options)
    700         if ioargs.encoding and "b" not in ioargs.mode:
    701             # Encoding
--> 702             handle = open(
    703                 handle,
    704                 ioargs.mode,

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'script\\output\x821\x821-CW51\x8211221\\DONE\x8211221_A.csv'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use forward slashes instead of backslashes in the file path.

Comment: .. or add `r"` prefix

Comment: The direction of the slashes could be your problem. Also make sure your `cwd` is what you think it is (some folder containing for folder `script`).

Comment: Was the forward slashes, thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Try using foward slashes (/). If that doesnt work try using absolute paths, convert relative paths to absolute with this function:

```
import os
def relative2absolute (relative):
    return os.path.join (os.getcwd (), relative)
```